# Test class for Http callout in pagereference method

Tags: unit-test

i am new to salesforce.i created a class for creating custom fields using metadata.my class is working fine. But it's something fishy to write a test class for this class. plz help me.

**controller class:**

```
global with sharing class createnew
{
public string getnames;
public string getfield;
public set<id>ids;
public list<Build_custom_field__c> linked;
public list<Build_custom_field__c> linked1;
public list<Build_custom_field__c> linked2;
List<String> stdObjectNames = new List<String>();
ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
public createnew(){
ids=new set<id>();
}
public createnew(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
{
    setcon=controller;
    ids=new set<id>();
    linked2=new list<Build_custom_field__c>();
}


public pagereference neww()
{

    linked=new list<Build_custom_field__c>();
    linked=[select id,Reference_Object__c,object_names__c,data_type__C,field_name__C,formula_return_type__C from Build_custom_field__c where created__C=:false];
    system.debug('5555*******'+linked.size());
    if(linked.size()>0)
    {
    for(Build_custom_field__c link:linked)
    {
     getfield=link.field_name__C+'__c';
     if(getfield.contains(' '))
     {
     getfield=getfield.replace(' ','_');
     system.debug('*******'+getfield);
     }
     system.debug('*******'+link);
     ids.add(link.id);
//Schema.DescribeSObjectResult parentObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('link.Reference_Object__c').getDescribe();
    HTTP h = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'create');

    String b = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    b += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
    b += '<soapenv:Header>';
    b += '<ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
    b += '<ns1:sessionId>' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</ns1:sessionId>';
    b += '</ns1:SessionHeader>';
    b += '</soapenv:Header>';
    b += '<soapenv:Body>';
    b += '<create xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
    b += '<metadata xsi:type="ns2:CustomField" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
   if(link.data_type__C=='text')
    {
    b += '<fullName>'+link.object_names__c+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b += '<length>100</length>';
    b += '<type>text</type>';  
    }
   if(link.data_type__C=='Number'){
    b += '<fullName>'+link.object_names__c+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b += '<type>Number</type>';
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b += '<scale>2</scale>';
    b += '<precision>10</precision>';  
    }
   if(link.data_type__C=='formula'){
    b += '<fullName>'+link.object_names__c+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b += '<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b += '<type>'+link.formula_return_type__C+'</type>';
    if(link.formula_return_type__C =='Number' || link.formula_return_type__C=='Currency' || link.formula_return_type__C=='Percent')
    {
    b += '<scale>2</scale>';
    b += '<precision>10</precision>';
    }
    b += '<formula>null</formula>'; 
    b += '<unique>false</unique>'; 
    b += '<required>false</required>';  
    }

   if(link.data_type__C=='LongTextArea'){
    b += '<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b += '<type>LongTextArea</type>';
    b += '<length>32000</length>';
    b += '<visibleLines >3</visibleLines >'; 
    }

   if(link.data_type__C=='Date'){
    b += '<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b += '<defaultValue>TODAY()</defaultValue>';
    b += ' <externalId>false</externalId>';
    b += '<required>false</required>';
    b += '<type>Date</type>';
    }

   if(link.data_type__C=='Checkbox'){
    b += '<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b += '<defaultValue>false</defaultValue>';
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b += '<type>Checkbox</type>'; 
    }

   if(link.data_type__C=='Phone'){
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>'; 
    b += '<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b += '<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b += '<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b += '<type>Phone</type>'; 
    }

   if(link.data_type__C=='Picklist'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<picklist>';
    b += '<picklistValues>';
    b +='<fullName>AD</fullName>';
    b +='<default>false</default>';
    b +='</picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues>';
    b +='<fullName>FG</fullName>';
    b +='<default>false</default>';
    b +='</picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues>';
    b +='<fullName>GG</fullName>';
    b +='<default>false</default>'; 
    b +='</picklistValues>';
    b +='<sorted>false</sorted>';
    b +='</picklist>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>Picklist</type>';
    }
   if(link.data_type__C=='AutoNumber'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<displayFormat>AN - {0000}</displayFormat>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<inlineHelpText>Auto Number Field</inlineHelpText>';
    b += '<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +=' <type>AutoNumber</type>'; 
    }

   if(link.data_type__C=='DateTime'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<defaultValue>Now()</defaultValue>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<type>DateTime</type>';
    }    
   if(link.data_type__C=='Currency'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<defaultValue>2000</defaultValue>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<precision>16</precision>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<scale>2</scale>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>Currency</type>';
    }      
   if(link.data_type__C=='Email'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<unique>false</unique>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>Email</type>';
    } 
   if(link.data_type__C=='Location'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<displayLocationInDecimal>false</displayLocationInDecimal>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<scale>5</scale>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>Location</type>';
    }  
   if(link.data_type__C=='MultiselectPicklist'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<picklist>';
    b +='<picklistValues><fullName>ant</fullName><default>true</default></picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues><fullName>cat</fullName><default>true</default></picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues><fullName>rat</fullName><default>true</default></picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues><fullName>eat</fullName><default>true</default></picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues><fullName>mat</fullName><default>true</default></picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues><fullName>sort</fullName><default>true</default></picklistValues>';
    b +='<picklistValues><fullName>array</fullName><default>true</default></picklistValues>';
    b +='</picklist>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>MultiselectPicklist</type>';
    b +='<visibleLines>4</visibleLines>';
    }  
   if(link.data_type__C=='Percent'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<defaultValue>0.023</defaultValue>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<precision>18</precision>';
    b +='<scale>5</scale>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>Percent</type>';
    }  
   if(link.data_type__C=='TextAreaRich'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<length>32768</length>';
    b +='<inlineHelpText>Text Area Rich Help</inlineHelpText>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>Html</type>';
    b +='<visibleLines>25</visibleLines>';
    }  
   if(link.data_type__C=='TextEncripted'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<description>This field is created using Metadata.</description>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<length>20</length>';
    b +='<inlineHelpText>Text Area Rich Help</inlineHelpText>';
    b +='<maskChar>asterisk</maskChar>';
    b +='<maskType>all</maskType>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>EncryptedText</type>';
    } 
   if(link.data_type__C=='MasterDetail'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<referenceTo>'+link.reference_object__C+'</referenceTo>';
    b +='<relationshipLabel>Metadata</relationshipLabel>';
    b +='<relationshipName>Metadata</relationshipName>';
    b +='<relationshipOrder>0</relationshipOrder>';
    b +='<reparentableMasterDetail>false</reparentableMasterDetail>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>MasterDetail</type>';
    b +='<writeRequiresMasterRead>false</writeRequiresMasterRead>';
    } 
    if(link.data_type__C=='Lookup'){
    b +='<fullName>'+link.object_names__C+'.'+getfield+'</fullName>';
    b +='<externalId>false</externalId>';
    b +='<deleteConstraint>SetNull</deleteConstraint>';
    b +='<label>'+link.field_name__C+'</label>';
    b +='<referenceTo>'+link.reference_object__C+'</referenceTo>';
    b +='<relationshipLabel>Metadata</relationshipLabel>';
    b +='<relationshipName>Metadata</relationshipName>';
    b +='<required>false</required>';
    b +='<trackHistory>false</trackHistory>';
    b +='<type>Lookup</type>';
    System.debug('body=='+b);

    } 

    b += '</metadata>';
    b += '</create>';
    b += '</soapenv:Body>';
    b += '</soapenv:Envelope>';      
    req.setBody(b);
    req.setCompressed(false);
    req.setEndpoint('https://rubavarnan-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/25.0');
    HTTPResponse resp = h.send(req);
    System.debug('dddd'+resp.getBody());

    }
    }

 if(linked.size()>0)
 { 
      linked1=new list<Build_custom_field__c>();
      linked1=[select id,Reference_Object__c,object_names__C,data_type__C,field_name__C from Build_custom_field__c where id in:ids];
      for(Build_custom_field__c one:linked1)
      {

      one.created__c=true;
      linked2.add(one);
      }
      if(linked2.size()>0)
      {
      upsert linked2;
      }
 }
PageReference pr = new pagereference('/a0I?fcf=00B28000005YXDS');
return pr;

}
}
```

I think i should follow **Httpmockcallout** implementation.but i don't know how to start my test class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of what the test might look like:

```
@IsTest
private class CreateNewTest {

    private class Mock implements HttpCalloutMock {

        String dataType;
        Boolean called = false;

        Mock(String dataType) {
            this.dataType = dataType;
        }

        public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {

            called = true;

            if (dataType == 'text') {
                ... assert that req is as expected
            } else if (dataType == 'Number') {
                ... assert that req is as expected
            } else if ...

            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setBody(...);
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }


    @IsTest
    static void testText() {
        test('text');
    }

    @IsTest
    static void testNumber() {
        test('Number');
    }

    ...

    private static void test(String dataType) {

        Mock m = new Mock(dataType);

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, m);

        Build_custom_field__c b = new Build_custom_field__c(
                data_type__C = dataType,
                created__C = false,
                ...
                };
        insert b;

        createnew c = new createnew(new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
                new Build_custom_field__c[] {}
                ));
        c.neww();

        System.assert(m.called);
    }
}
```

Best study e.g. [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) and [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) to be able to fill in the details more completely.